# UILocalNotifcation - Respond to notification even if app launched via home screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am sending out local notifications within my app; if the user responds to the notification the app calls the delegate method below and I can handle it:

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif
```

If the user doesn't respond to the notification but opens the app after, I would like to handle it the same way I would if they responded to the notification.

I also checked if the app is launching with launch options but this only seems to be called if they respond directly to the notification.

What is the best way to check that a notification has been fired but the user has responded of their own accord?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to keep track of which notifications you've scheduled yourself. You can use UIApplication's `scheduledLocalNotifications` to see which ones are still scheduled; if you compare that list to the list of notification you know you've scheduled, you can see which ones have been fired.

Comment: This seems a little annoying. so the best way is keep an array of notification, and compare which one is missing?

Comment: Well, the OS has no way of knowing if the user is "responding" to any particular notification; many could have gone off since you last launched the app. I think you probably want to keep track of whatever the notifications represent (timers? events?) and then see if those things have passed. If you want, you could use `scheduledLocalNotifications` to see what's still scheduled, but I think you'd be better of just looking at your data to see what's happened since last time.

Comment: Thanks for this- but don't think its going to work as some of my reminders are repeated so there for appear scheduled

Comment: Right; that's why I'm saying you probably just need to calculate yourself what happened since last time.